# Where is hudson.model.Item.Move permission object defined?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins allows granting members (users and groups) `Item.Move` (Job → Move) permission by using UI:

[image: Configure Permissions]

Unfortunately, `Item.Move` permission it is not defined in `hudson.model.Item` class. All other permissions are available:

- `Build` → `Item.BUILD`
- `Cancel` → `Item.CANCEL`
- `Configure` → `Item.CONFIGURE`
- etc.

Where is defined the `hudson.security.Permission` object which represents `Item.Move` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission is introduced by [CloudBees Folders](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cloudbees-folder) plugin. It is defined in the `com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.relocate.RelocationAction` class:

```
/**
 * Does the actual work of relocating an item.
 */
@Restricted(NoExternalUse.class)
public class RelocationAction implements Action, StaplerFallback, IconSpec {

    /**
     * The permission required to move an item.
     */
    public static final Permission RELOCATE = new Permission(Item.PERMISSIONS, "Move", Messages._RelocateAction_permission_desc(), Permission.CREATE, PermissionScope.ITEM);
```

Link to the class located in the 6.10.1 version: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin/blob/cloudbees-folder-6.10.1/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/relocate/RelocationAction.java#L56

Comment: For any future readers, you would call it via: `com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.relocate.RelocationAction.RELOCATE`